# How do you create a list of bullet points in a QLabel?

Tags: python, pyside2

Using Python and PySide2, how do you create a list of bullet points in a QLabel widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML for this.

```
label.setText("<html><ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul></html>")
```